# Check If Shell Script $1 Is Absolute Or Relative Path

Tags: bash, shell

As the title says, I am trying to determine if my bash script receives a full path or a relative file to a directory as a parameter.

For some reasons the following doesn't seem to work for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$1

if [ "$DIR" = /* ]
then
    echo "absolute"
else
    echo "relative"
fi
```

When I run my script with either a full path or absolute path it says:

```
./script.sh: line 5: [: too many arguments
relative
```

For some reasons I can't seem to figure this bug. Any ideas?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`[ ... ]` doesn't do pattern matching. `/*` is being expanded to the contents of `/`, so effectively you have

```
if [ "$DIR" = /bin /boot /dev /etc /home /lib /media ... /usr /var ]
```

or something similar. Use `[[ ... ]]` instead.

```
if [[ "$DIR" = /* ]]; then
```

For POSIX compliance, or if you just don't have a `[[` that does pattern matching, use a `case` statement.

```
case $DIR in
  /*) echo "absolute path" ;;
  *) echo "something else" ;;
esac
```

Comment: If i give this path `/home/user/folder1/../folder2` which is relative it will output that it's absolute which is wrong.

Comment: A relative path is one that refers to different files, depending on what the current working directory is. That path always refers to `/home/user/folder2`, so it is an absolute path. `..` isn't just a shell shortcut; it's a very real entry in the file system for the parent of the directory it is contained in.

Comment: Apparently this only works for bash, not for (a)sh

Comment: No, `[[` is an extension supported by `bash` and some other shells. I'll add a POSIX-compliant version to the answer.

Answer (score 35):

Just test on the first character:

```
if [ "${DIR:0:1}" = "/" ]
```

Comment: Works well in `bash` (and `ksh` and `zsh`), but just to avoid potential confusion: despite the use of `[ ... ]` and `=`, this solution is not POSIX-compliant (the POSIX shell spec. doesn't support positional substring extraction). If POSIX compliance is not a requirement, as in this case, it's generally better to use `[[ ... ]]`: `[[ "${DIR:0:1}" == '/' ]]` (or even `[[ ${DIR:0:1} == '/' ]]`).

Answer (score 9):

One more case is paths started from `~` (tilde). `~user/some.file` or `~/some.file` are some kind of absolute paths.

```
if [[ "${dir:0:1}" == / || "${dir:0:2}" == ~[/a-z] ]]
then
    echo "Absolute"
else
    echo "Relative"
fi
```

Answer (score 7):

[ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically points out that "`[ .. ] can't match globs. Use [[ .. ]] or grep.`"

In other words, use

```
if [[ "$DIR" = /* ]]
```

This is because `[` is a regular command, so `/*` is expanded by the shell beforehand, turning it into

```
[ "$DIR" = /bin /dev /etc /home .. ]
```

`[[` is handled specially by the shell, and doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Writing tests is fun:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a MY_ARRAY # declare an indexed array variable

MY_ARRAY[0]="/a/b"
MY_ARRAY[1]="a/b"
MY_ARRAY[2]="/a a/b"
MY_ARRAY[3]="a a/b"
MY_ARRAY[4]="/*"


# Note that 
# 1) quotes around MY_PATH in the [[ ]] test are not needed
# 2) the expanded array expression "${MY_ARRAY[@]}" does need the quotes
#    otherwise paths containing spaces will fall apart into separate elements.
# Nasty, nasty syntax.

echo "Test with == /* (correct, regular expression match according to the Pattern Matching section of the bash man page)"

for MY_PATH in "${MY_ARRAY[@]}"; do
   # This works
   if [[ $MY_PATH == /* ]]; then
      echo "'$MY_PATH' is absolute"
   else
      echo "'$MY_PATH' is relative"
   fi
done

echo "Test with == \"/*\" (wrong, becomes string comparison)"

for MY_PATH in "${MY_ARRAY[@]}"; do
   # This does not work at all; comparison with the string "/*" occurs!
   if [[ $MY_PATH == "/*" ]]; then
      echo "'$MY_PATH' is absolute"
   else
      echo "'$MY_PATH' is relative"
   fi
done

echo "Test with = /* (also correct, same as ==)"

for MY_PATH in "${MY_ARRAY[@]}"; do
   if [[ $MY_PATH = /* ]]; then
      echo "'$MY_PATH' is absolute"
   else
      echo "'$MY_PATH' is relative"
   fi
done

echo "Test with =~ /.* (pattern matching according to the regex(7) page)"

# Again, do not quote the regex; '^/' would do too

for MY_PATH in "${MY_ARRAY[@]}"; do
   if [[ $MY_PATH =~ ^/[:print:]* ]]; then
      echo "'$MY_PATH' is absolute"
   else
      echo "'$MY_PATH' is relative"
   fi
done
```

Comment: How about testing ~/a/b path?